# Automatically add braces

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, curly-braces

**How can I configure eclipse to behave in the way described below?**

I have some code, like this:

```java
for(int x: someList)
    if(x == y)
        doSomething();
    else if(x == z)
        doSomethingElse();
    else satisfiesCondition(x)
        x = someFunction(x);
```

And I have decided that I want to add another statement to the `if(x == z)` part.

I place my cursor at the end of the line, like this:

```java
    else if(x == z)█ //here
        doSomethingElse();█ //or here
```

Then I press <kbd>enter</kbd>/<kbd>return</kbd>, and it automatically adds braces to the block, like this:

```java
for(int x: someList)
    if(x == y)
        doSomething();
    else if(x == z){
        █ //if it was at the end of the else
        doSomethingElse();
        █ //if it was at the end of the `doSomethingElse();` statement
    } else
        x = someFunction(x);
```

And then, I want to add something to the end of the `for` block, so I put my cursor here:

```java
        x = someFunction(x);
█
```

I press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and it does this:

```java
for(int x: someList){
    if(x == y)
        doSomething();
    else if(x == z){
        doSomethingElse();
        doSomeThirdThing();
    } else
        x = someFunction(x);
    █
}
```

Then, I decide I actually want to add the statement to the else block, not the for block, so I press <kbd>tab</kbd> again, and it moves the braces, so it's like this:

```java
for(int x: someList)
    if(x == y)
        doSomething();
    else if(x == z){
        doSomethingElse();
        doSomeThirdThing();
    } else {
        x = someFunction(x);
        █
    }
```

Comment: This looks nice and I think it could be possible to add this kind of functionality with a plugin. The eclipse editor itself doesn't allow to be configured this way through the regular options.

Comment: Also, is there some way to make eclipse automatically increase or decrease the indentation of code when braces are added or removed?

Comment: @AJMansfield: it's not automatic, but highlight a block of code and press Ctrl-Shift-F to format the highlighted block.